# .htaccess for handheld mobile file version redirects

Tags: php, .htaccess, mobile

I am using Godaddy with the cheapest Linux hosting package and no extra or special configurations. I need help with a complete .htaccess to redirect pages in folders for a single extra mobile version of site pages. It's very basic.

I have a second version of the PHP site files for the mobile version in the format of [filename].php to [filename].mobile.php that also includes the index.php and index.mobile.php. I do have a link top and bottom for users to manually go to the mobile or full site version. I am lost on .htaccess files, can someone help me?

Comment: If someone goes to index.mobile.php, won't all the links in the page still be to the non-mobile versions? Maybe you should modify these in your app, rather than in htaccess?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far? There are [loads](http://codular.com/htaccess-introduction) [of](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess.shtml) [great](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) .htaccess tutorials - use one of those, and ask for any specific issues that aren't working.

Comment: Thank you. They are all separate pages. A second version of all the site pages. About 50-60 total. The main problem is I am not programmer. I used php only to enable *includes* for the html content that is sometimes repeated. I wouldn't mind adding some php to each page header if that would work better, but as I said, I'm not a programmer. You tell me which would be better. I have a .htaccess in the root directory, but it is 3-4 years old and doesn't work. The way smart phones have exploded lately, I need to do something. I thought .htaccess would be the best, but I'm wide open to suggestions.

Comment: I have looked a dozens of related htaccess redirect scripts on this site, but none were what I was looking for unless I edited it just right to check for smart phones but not tablets and redirect to the mobile page, but still allow the manual link to work also. It would be great to redirect visitors automatically. Can you give me a link to the one here that is closest to that, and possibly suggest the syntax correction for my purposes? It would be much appreciated.